# uitableview adds new values to stack any way to flush or release?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1KGb.png this is my tablecells,

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {

                long selected = tableItemsX [indexPath.Row].Id;

                up.btn2.Clicked += delegate {
                    Console.Write (selected);
                };
```

if I choose multiple cells, after I click btn2; gets me all selected row Id, but I need only last clicked row value.

I get different values with indxpath.row.id, but if I click btn gives me all rows. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you select a row, you are adding a new handler to btn2.  You should only assign a handler once.

```
// put this in your ViewDidLoad
up.btn2.Clicked += delegate {
  Console.Write (selected);
};


// declare selected as a class level variable
long selected;

public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
  selected = tableItemsX [indexPath.Row].Id;
}
```